# filter array and return the object containing the closest strings inside array inside an object, inside another array

Tags: javascript, arrays, string, filter

I want to return the object containing the closest strings inside array inside an object, inside another array,
my `indexOf()` only return the exact string as true.

I tried replacing `indexOf()` with `march()`, `matches()`, `includes()` nothing works.

Please advice

```
let SellerList = [
  { supplyList: ["apple", "orange", "red apple"] },
  { supplyList: ["apple juice", "drink", "green apple", "dream app"] },
  { supplyList: ["lamp", "dog", "cat", "man"] }
];

let stringToMatch = "app";

let filteredList = SellerList.filter(
  (txt) => txt.supplyList.indexOf(stringToMatch) !== -1
);
```

the output i wish for is all the objects containing the closest strings for example:

```
[
  { supplyList: ["apple", "orange", "red apple"] },
  { supplyList: ["apple juice", "drink", "green apple", "dream app"] }
];
```

Comment: from the search term `app` that show what the expected result would be and why? and is there more than one object in array `SellerList`?

Comment: @Mario yes i have more then one

Comment: For `stringToMatch = "app"` what is the expected output?

Comment: @Mario all the objects containing the closest strings for example: see my question i edit it with expected output example

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please try the following solution

```js
let SellerList = [
  { supplyList: ["apple", "orange", "red apple"] },
  { supplyList: ["apple juice", "drink", "green apple", "dream app"] },
  { supplyList: ["lamp", "dog", "cat", "man"] },
];

let stringToMatch = "app";

let filteredList = SellerList.reduce((previousValue, currentValue) => {
  if (currentValue.supplyList.join().includes(stringToMatch)) {
    previousValue = [...previousValue, { supplyList: currentValue.supplyList }];
  }

  return previousValue;
}, []);

console.log(filteredList);
```

See

- [Array.prototype.reduce()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reduce)
- [Array.prototype.join()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/join)

Answer (score 2):

You have an array inside an object, inside another array, so you want to target that inner array and call filter on it:

```js
let SellerList = [{
  supplyList: ['apple', 'orange', 'red apple']
}];

let stringToMatch = 'app';

let filteredList = SellerList[0].supplyList.filter(txt => txt.indexOf(stringToMatch) !== -1);

console.log(filteredList)
```

Comment: thanks, but how can i do it when i have more then one object ? in the array with another inside strings array ?

Answer (score 0):

You should try to match the inner strings of the supplyLists instead of the arrays themselves.

```js
let SellerList = [ 
                     { supplyList: ['apple','orange','red apple'] },
                     { supplyList: ['apple juice','drink','green apple'] } 
                   ];
  
  let stringToMatch = 'app';

  let filteredList = SellerList.map(list => {
    
    return list.supplyList.filter(item => {
      return item.indexOf(stringToMatch) >= 0
    })
  
  });
  
  
  console.log(filteredList);
```

Comment: thanks, how do i reruen the object containing the closest strings ?
for example: { supplyList: ['apple juice','drink','green apple'] } 
i also edited my question with expected output